# What is the correct method to get sub-resources for filtered resources in REST?

Tags: rest, filter, resources

Working with a REST api, lets say we have a resource 'students' and a subresource 'classes'.

In a contrived example say we want to find all the classes taken by students whose surname is 'Smith'.

What would be the correct way to construct a uri for this scenario? I thought of the following:

```
GET: /api/students?surname=smith/classes
```

but that looks awkward to me.

EDIT:

Given the answers and comments, I think the answer does indeed lie in turning the request around. I could have something like

```
GET: /api/classes?student-surname=smith
```

and let the API handle it.

Comment: Agree with Justas as you should not have query parameters and then a new resource path

Answer (score 2):

You can think other way - classes folder contains students - and change to:

```
GET: /api/classes/students?surname=smith
```

Or

```
GET: /api/classes/{classId}/students?surname=smith
```

Comment: My thinking agrees with Jacques that you shouldn't have query parameters then a new resource path.

Comment: However Justas won't this give me all students with surname Smith as long as they are enrolled in at least one class? I don't think it will give me classes which have a student with surname Smith. Regardless your answer is stirring something in my brain. I have to do some more thinking but I'm sure the answer is just there.

Comment: It would return students with surname Smith who enrolled in at least one class.

Comment: That's what I thought. I am looking to find the classes in which these students are enrolled.